# basic url rewriting to from from rewritten URL to real URL and viceversa

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am completely new to URL rewriting.
I read a few articles and followed a few examples so I know that with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

I can redirect my visitors from www.domain.com/Home to www.domain.com/index.php?p=Home

What I would like to understand is, once a user clicks on a link from the home page that points him/her to www.domain.com/index.php?p=Biography can I make the URL bar of the browser show www.domain.com/Biography instead of the real URL?

Can this all be done within the .htaccess file or should I do it from within PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Place this code in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?p=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @anubhava that works perfectly now! just one question, how can I set exceptions for some pages that I don't want URLs to be rewritten for?

Comment: For adding exceptions you can add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(page1|page2)` conditions before any `RewriteRule`

Comment: @anubhava thank you for your insights... just to make sure that I am doing this right. so I would like to exclude url rewriting for all the files that end with the word "edit" in the name of the variable p, so I have added the following as my very first rule of the .htaccess file: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php\?p=(.*edit&)/ [NC] - could you please confirm that I understood this correctly? thank you so much!

Comment: What are examples of full URLs you want to exclude? And just fyi full url starts with `http://` or `https://`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57642/discussion-between-marcnyc-and-anubhava).

Comment: @anubhava I am trying to INCLUDE urls such as: http://domain.com/index.php?p=Portfolio&ms=m2&l=en& http://domain.com/index.php?p=Home&ms=m1 etc while at the same time I am trying to EXCLUDE urls such as: http://domain.com/index.php?p=pageedit&l=en or http://domain.com/index.php?p=contactedit&l=en - right now incidentally (after adding that line I posted earlier) I am seeing the strange behavior that the "Home" url is correctly rewritten but the "Portfolio" one is not!

Comment: ok try this one: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?p=((?![^&]*?edit)[^\s&]+) [NC]`

Comment: @anubhava PERFECT! Thank you so much... just ONE LAST THING I need to bother you with because I forgot earlier... I also need to exclude domain.com/index.php?p=admin&l=en - I tried adding RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?p=(admin|((?![^&]*?edit)[^\s&]+)) [NC] but that doesn't work - I am sorry I don't understand all of this that well

Comment: At this point i sincerely suggest you opening a new question with all the new requirements. I have tried to accommodate as much as possible but if you notice your original question with latest problems there is a very wide gap. Usually SO questions are for solving a particular problem.

Comment: @anubhava I understand. Thank you so much for your kindness, generosity and your time